# Communicating between two threads android

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

I have an intent service which runs on a thread A and another thread B which I execute from intent service to execute some tasks, once thread B has finished working I want to send the result back to thread A through handler. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
 Log.d("service", "service is started!");


         handler=new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  if(msg.arg1==1){

                  }
                }
            };

            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker=new BackgroundWorker(handler);
            Thread thread=new Thread(backgroundWorker);
            thread.start();

        }
```

And this is thread B class:

```
class BackgroundWorker implements Runnable{

        private Handler handler;

        public BackgroundWorker(Handler handler){
            this.handler=handler;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

              Looper.prepare();
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.arg1 =  1;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
              Looper.loop();


        }
    }
```

So my problem is I am sending the message in backgroundWorker class but it's never received in handleMessage.

Comment: An intentservice runs in a separate thread by default, you don't need to start a separate thread yourself

Comment: i am starting another thread because i want to destroy the thread B  if user pressed the cancel button and i don't want to block the intent service

Comment: @Tim Castelijns i found the problem it seems that intent service is destroyed once onhandleintent is finished

Comment: Yes it is destroyed after onhandleintent

Comment: yup i think i should use service :(